# Export use state

Tags: arrays, reactjs

**Here is my first code**

```
export default function CustomizedTables() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(temporary);

  return (
   ***Block of code***
)
};
```

**I take input from user in another file**

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Class" onChange={(e)=>setStuClass(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Batch" onChange={(e)=>setBatch(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Roles" onChange={(e)=>setRole(e.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={inputHandler}>Add</button>
        </div>
   ***Other Block of code***
</div>
```

**Here is my Function**

```
const inputHandler = ()=>{
    let data2 = {
        name,
        stuClass,
        batch,
        roles
    }
}
```

***Now I want to export it into first file. So, I can update useState***

Comment: there's no way to export your state. you've to use some context provider such as React Context or Redux.

Comment: you need to pass component with props. So then you could take out all of the data, where you use useState.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export your state, you either pass it as a prop or you create a context / redux store and get it from there.

Comment: Since this isn't much of an answer I guess it should be a comment.